# Take a list and return random elements in ordered pairs (must be mutable)

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list I want to take random pieces out of that are 2 at a time. If my list is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... I want to return 2 and 3 or 3 and 4 or 1 and 2 but not 1 and 4 etc. I know how to use random and its reading from a file and converted into a list called "word" so can I iterate over "word" and pull any two random words that are right next to each other and pass them in a pair to a new variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick a random index from `0` to `n-2` (where `n` is the length of the list), then pick that index and it's adjacent value:

```
from random import randint
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
index = randint(0, len(lst)-2)
pair = lst[index:index+2]  # return [4, 5] or [1, 2], etc..
```

This returns a list which is mutable.

Comment: Okay great, that would work just fine. I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: what if my items in my list are strings?

Comment: Then you will get pairs of strings instead of pairs of numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right! It was my logic screwed up I understand what you did now though and definitely learned from it. Ill be sure to pass the buck to the next guy lol thanks Martin!!